# Connecting from GDScript class to Node won't run function

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

So I have a game I'm making and I'm making a dash mechanic. I have a player class that the player nodes (that are character2D nodes) inherit from. I (mostly) made it so the player needs to have a dash bar filled up so they can dash. I need to have a signal that resets the players dash meter, and it will connect, but it won't run the function. (I'm using Godot 4.0)

Character2D Script

```
func _ready():
    player.remove_dash.connect(_remove_all_dash)
    print("is connected: " + str(player.remove_dash.is_connected(_remove_all_dash)))
    
func _remove_all_dash():
    dash_power = 0
    print("function ran")
```

Player class script

```
func check_for_dash_input(delta, player_resource: Resource, dash_timer: Timer, input: String, dash_power: int):
    dash(delta, player_resource, dash_timer, dash_power)
    
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed(input):
        dash_timer.start()
            emit_signal("remove_dash")
            print("signal emit")
```

Debug console:
is connected: true;
signal emit

I tried looking a the docs for Godot 4.0, but that didn't really help.

Comment: My first guess is that there are multiple player objects, and the wrong one is being connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turned out I had to actually set the Player Class in the editor because when I make a Character2D and connect signal, it didn't work.

[how to set player class in the editor][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W77Iv.png

Answer (score 0):

I think signals are really complicated to debug without having the actual project on hand.... but maybe it has something to do with the inheratance?

I guess you could also set a dash_power to 0 in the Player class instead of the Character2D and instead in the Character2D use the dashpower value from Player?